# Using q-scroll-area with div

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I'm adding q-scroll-area to existing content that works. When I add the q-scroll area, the conditional formatting of v-if does not work (either if I wrap the div with q-scroll-area or wrap it the other way). I want the div element to appear and be scrollable only on v-if show.

```js
    <div @click="show = !show">button</div>
    <div v-if="show">
    <q-scroll-area>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
    elit.  
    </q-scroll-area>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're attaching a click event to an element that will be removed from the DOM. Your click handler will execute only once.

Comment: You're right, and I'm sorry I left a bit of the code out. I had a button on top. Edited code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Quasar docs, they set a fixed height to `<q-scroll-area>` for *vertical content*. Seems that *q-scroll-area* has a height of 0 by default.

```js
<div @click="show = !show">button</div>
  <div v-if="show">
    <q-scroll-area style="height: 200px; max-width: 300px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
    elit.  
    </q-scroll-area>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but that hasn't worked. It drops down an area that size, but there is no visible text. Interestingly I can see the text in devtools. I'm thinking there is CSS I can work through.

Comment: Try to surround your text in a `div`.

Comment: I tried that. When i copy/paste the page into a word document, the text shows. I think the position is off. I'm seeing these div elements generated by quasar: <div class="q-scrollarea__container scroll relative-position fit hide-scrollbar"><div class="q-scrollarea__content absolute">

Comment: Fixed by attaching the class of z-top to the inner div! Thank you!